# My attempt at a Riley

Tags: riddle, word

I seem not to be good at solving Rileys, maybe I'm better at creating them. Here you go:

> About the prefix, I couldn't tell you less.
>   The suffix is about half of you, I guess.
>   The infix, well, it clearly is not me.
>   The solution now materialized should be.

<sub>Besides solution attempts, any feedback is appreciated.</sub>

Comment: Feedback: Difficult, good.

Comment: This was a satisfying puzzle, I thought the first line was very clever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a work in progress.

I think you are:

> bitumen (asphalt)

About the prefix, I couldn't tell you less.

> A bit is the smallest unit of data in a computer, you could not convey less information than that

The suffix is about half of you, I guess.

> We assume half of the readers are men

The infix, well, it clearly is not me.

> The opposite of me would be you, or "u"

The solution now materialized should be.

> Unfortunately I'm still not sure how this ties in. Perhaps it is a reference to the process through which bitumen is created

Comment: Congratulations, you've found the solution! About the last part: Think about what it is.

Comment: I think the last line would be called a rot13(nanfgebcur), but I can't make the connection from there. I can't see how the last line could be anything more than a hint, because the solution can be found with just the first three lines.

Comment: I meant: Think about the solution. What is it that the word describes? And yes, the line is a hint at the solution (as are all lines, actually).

Comment: rot13(Vg vf na vaqhfgevny ovaqre hfrq gb cebqhpr, be zngrevnyvmr, nfcunyg sebz bgure fhofgnaprf. Guvf vf fvzvyne gb ubj gur guerr cevbe uvagf ner obhaq gbtrgure gb sbez gur jubyr jbeq.)

Comment: rot13(Npghnyyl ovghzra vf nabgure anzr sbe nfcunyg; V'z abg njner bs vg nyfb orvat hfrq gb anzr gur cebprff.)

Comment: @celtschk does it mean it is a solid?

Comment: @Pheo: What's the substantive "materialized" is derived from?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is

> lesson

About the prefix, I couldn't tell you less.

> You can't tell us less because that would be giving away the prefix

The suffix is about half of you, I guess.

> We assume half of the readers are male

The infix, well, it clearly is not me.

> Esso sounds like "SO", meaning "significant other", or clearly not "me"

Comment: Interesting solution, but not what I meant. You also didn't explain the last line.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is

> human

About the prefix, I couldn't tell you less.

> If asked a question and you hum, "Hmmmmm..." you couldn't be telling us less

The suffix is about half of you, I guess.

> Guessing half the reads are male (man) the other half female.

The infix, well, it clearly is not me.

> "u" i.e. "you" isn't me

The solution now materialized should be.

> You, i.e. celtschk, now materialialize before us as a human

Comment: You got quite a few things right, but not everything. In particular, not the prefix.